# Do I need to use Bonferroni correction in commutation study?

Tags: p-value, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

I have a table like this:

```
                Mutation_2_Present   Mutation_2_Absent
Mutation_1_Present     982                  740181
Mutation_1_Absent      111555               89355602
```

And I apply the Fisher test etc. The thing is that mutation 1 and 2 are not from gene A vs gene B.

They just corresponds to category1 gene and category2 gene.
So for example.

```
cat1 cat2
A B
A C
A D
G C
Z X
```

So I grouped all genes into either cat1 or cat2. And then I counted the times they appeared in a population.

```
                Mutation_in_cat2_Present   Mutation_in_cat2_Absent
Mutation_in_cat1_Present     982                  740181
Mutation_in_cat1_Absent      111555               89355602
```

Do I have to apply Bonferroni correction here, or is my hypothesis a single one? To see if mutations in cat1 and cat2 genes appear more often than expected together.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are reporting the results of one test or two tests? More specifically, are you saying you discovered a data issue after performing primary inference and so you had to revise your analysis to be done on the corrected data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only perform one significance test, you do not need to use a multiple comparisons correction. The way you describe your problem, you are pooling together different sources of data into one 2-way table, and then applying the statistical test to that single table. So, you are only performing one statistical test, and thus do not need to apply multiple comparisons correction.

Answer (score 0):

Bonferroni correction is specifically applied to control the familywise error rate (FWER). That is, you aim to report an honest significance level - a risk at which you would reject at least one hypothesis when all hypotheses are in fact false. When we conceptualize a "family" of hypotheses, it does not matter if they are different hypotheses, or the same hypothesis with different testing strategies applied. Making multiple attempts at rejecting the same null hypothesis requires control for multiple testing, or else you are $p$-hacking.

That said, if there are multiple tests of the same hypothesis, we should expect that these tests are correlated - perhaps not perfectly, but substantially so. In that case, Bonferroni is an inefficient method of controlling multiple testing and Benjamini Hochberg stepdown procedures could be employed instead.